# How can my HPCC docker container be accessed from another laptop?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, virtualbox, hpcc

I am running a HPCC Cluster in docker-compose in my laptop using docker-toolbox as I have Windows7. I can successfully connect to container (http://192.168.99.100:8010)

My **docker-compose.yml** file is:

```
version: '2'
services:
  hpcc-master:
    image: hpccsystems/platform-ce:6.4.4-1trusty
    command:  bash -c "cd /tmp; set -e && /tmp/run_master.sh"
    ports:
      - "8010:8010"
    links:
      - hpcc-thor
      - hpcc-roxie
    privileged: true
    tty: true
    environment:
      - MAX_ROXIE_INDEX=10
      - MAX_THOR_INDEX=10
      - SLAVES_PER_NODE=1
      #- DOWNLOAD_URL=https://github.com/xwang2713/HPCC-Docker
      #- DOWNLOAD_METHOD=git

  hpcc-thor:
    image: hpccsystems/platform-ce:6.4.4-1trusty
    privileged: true
    tty: true

  hpcc-roxie:
    image: hpccsystems/platform-ce:6.4.4-1trusty
    privileged: true
    tty: true

networks:
  default:
    external: 
      name: hpccbridge
```

Bridge was created with **docker network create hpccbridge**

docker ps output:
[image]

My IPs are:

[image]

**What I want** is my HPCC be reachable my another laptop (kind of http://10.55.58.59:8010)

**How can achieve this?**

Answer (score 1):

This is more a Virtual Box question rather than related to Docker. You can configure port forwarding in Virtual Box to do this:

1. Open VirtualBox Manager
2. Select your Docker Machine VirtualBox instance
3. Open Settings > Network > Advanced > Port Forwarding
4. Add a port forwarding rule

Comment: Added virtualbox tag